Ubuntu 22.04 invalid buffer destination
-bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory  
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.  
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,  
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for   
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is set properly.


The post lacks of a question and lacks of more explanation what you try to achieve. Please edit your question accordingly.
